# Multihomed General link with Search

Tags: sitecore-client

When we try to add an internal link to the "General Link with Search" field, a dialog box opens up which shows the tree structure based on the startSearchLocation parameter.

In my scenario, the items we want to add in here are present under multiple different nodes. Is there a way to show the items to be selected from all these nodes without showing the tree structure?

I have filtered based on templates so currently the Content Authors can select from the required template items only but the thing is since it still shows the entire tree that makes the task of Content Authors a little difficult to select the proper item.

Is it possible to just collate all the items from the different nodes and just show these, without custom coding? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!